# Angular2/4 broadcast service using RxJS

Tags: typescript, observer-pattern, angular-2+, rxjs

I am no expert in RxJS as I am still learning my way around the new paradigm of Observable/Subject.

I was trying to implement a broadcast service (based on NgRadio) that allows a new subscriber to get the nth last value of events he was listening to and the next emitted values after subscription.

As I stumbled upon issues with ReplaySubject to ask for the last n values... I ended up implementing it as follows. I feel that the code is not that crisp and clean so I would appreciate any improvement from more experienced RxJS developers.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
export interface RadioEvent {
    key: string;
    data?: any;
}

export class RadioService {
    private separator = ':';
    private _eventBus = new Subject<RadioEvent>();
    private _eventCacheBus = new ReplaySubject<RadioEvent>();

    keyMatch(key, wildcard) {
        var w = '*';
        var ww = '**';
        var partMatch = function (wl, k) {
            var match = (wl === w) || (wl === k);
            return match;    
        };
        var sep = this.separator;
        var kArr = key.split(sep);
        var wArr = wildcard.split(sep);
        var kLen = kArr.length;
        var wLen = wArr.length;
        var max = Math.max(kLen, wLen);
        for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
            var cK = kArr[i];
            var cW = wArr[i];
            // '**' match all gragments
            if (cW == ww && (typeof cK !== 'undefined')) {
                return true;
            }
            // test if fragments match
            if (!partMatch(cW, cK)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

    cast<T>(key: string, data?: any) {
        if (typeof key !== 'string' || !key.length) {
            throw 'Bad key. Please provide a string';
         }

        this._eventBus.next({ key: key, data: data });
        this._eventCacheBus.next({ key: key, data: data });
    };


    on<T>(key: string, count?: number) {
        var _this = this;
        var normalobs = this._eventBus
        .filter(function (event: RadioEvent) {
            return _this.keyMatch(event.key, key);
        }).map(function (event) {
            return event.data;
        });
        if (_.isNil(count)) {
            return normalobs;
        } else {
            let obs = this._eventCacheBus
            .filter(function (event: RadioEvent) {
                return _this.keyMatch(event.key, key);
            }).map(function (event) {
                return event.data;
            });
            let subject = new ReplaySubject<T>(count);
            obs.subscribe(value => {
                subject.next(value);
            })
            return Observable.merge(normalobs, subject).distinct();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your code works? Correct me if I am wrong, but `if (!partMatch(cW, cK)) { return false; }` should probably be `if (!partMatch(cW, cK)) { continue; }` or even `if (!partMatch(cW, cK)) { return true; }` instead, while the last instruction in `keyMatch()` should be `return false`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend you to ensure your code is correct (see my comment on your question).

Here are a few suggestions about improving your code.

- Please do not use non-informative names like `w, ww, sep, kArg, cW, CK`, and even the "well-known" `i, j, k, m, n`. They are absolutely horrible. They make decent code be an unreadable puzzle. They hide the intent and **make me think where I should not be**.
- Please always make sure you use Type when a) the compiler loses (or is unable to infer) the type information; b) you can narrow down the type. That includes the function return type. **Typing is not panacea but it helps prevent an entire class of bugs**.
- Do not use generic methods `smth<T>(...)` unless you use the type `T` information anywhere in the function.
- Minimize the distance between variable declaration, assignment, and first usage. Better declare and assign in the same place. Ideally, find a way to not even declare a variable.
- In error messages be more specific about what went wrong.

---

```
  const star = '*';
  const twoStars = '**';

  export class RadioService {
    private separator = ':';
    private _eventBus = new Subject<RadioEvent>();
    private _eventCacheBus = new ReplaySubject<RadioEvent>();

    keyMatch(keyList: string, wildcardList: string): boolean {
      const isMatch = (wildcard, key) => (wildcard === star) || (wildcard === key);

      const allKeys = keyList.split(this.separator);
      const allWildcards = wildcardList.split(this.separator);

      const keyWildcardPairs = allKeys
        .reduce((accum, current, index) => {
          accum.push([current, allWildcards[index]]);
          return accum;
        }, <string[][]>[]);

      return keyWildcardPairs.some(pair => {
        const key = pair[0];
        const wildcard = pair[1];
        // '**' match all gragments
        if (wildcard == twoStars && (typeof key !== 'undefined')) {
          return true;
        }
        // test if fragments match
        if (!isMatch(wildcard, key)) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
    };

    cast(key: string, data?: any): void {
      if (typeof key !== 'string' || key.length <= 0) {
        throw `Bad key '${JSON.stringify(key)}'. Please provide a non-empty string.`;
      }

      this._eventBus.next({ key: key, data: data });
      this._eventCacheBus.next({ key: key, data: data });
    };


    on(key: string, count?: number): Observable<any> {
      const _this = this;

      const normalObservable = this._eventBus
        .filter(event => _this.keyMatch(event.key, key))
        .map(event => event.data);

      const withoutReplay = _.isNil(count);
      if (withoutReplay)
        return normalObservable;

      const subject = new ReplaySubject<number>(count);
      this._eventCacheBus
        .filter(event => _this.keyMatch(event.key, key))
        .map(event => event.data)
        .subscribe(value => subject.next(value));

      return Observable
        .merge(normalObservable, subject)
        .distinct();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your reply. To be honest part of the code related the key matching algorithm was copied so I did not take the time to clean it up. This is code in case someone wants to use it with correction to your review keymatch implementation (using `.every()`):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, ReplaySubject, Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import * as _ from 'lodash';

const star = '*';
const twoStars = '**';

export interface RadioEvent {
    key: string;
    data?: any;
}

export class RadioService {
    private separator = ':';
    private _eventBus = new Subject<RadioEvent>();
    private _eventCacheBus = new ReplaySubject<RadioEvent>();

    public on(key: string, count?: number): Observable<any> {
        const _this = this;

        const normalObservable = this._eventBus
            .filter((event: RadioEvent) => _this.keyMatch(event.key, key))
            .map((event: RadioEvent) => event.data);

        const withoutReplay = _.isNil(count);
        if (withoutReplay) {
            return normalObservable;
        }

        const subject = new ReplaySubject<number>(count);
        this._eventCacheBus
            .filter((event: RadioEvent) => _this.keyMatch(event.key, key))
            .map((event: RadioEvent) => event.data)
            .subscribe((value) => subject.next(value));

        return Observable
            .merge(normalObservable, subject)
            .distinct();
    }

    public cast(_key: string, _data?: any): void {
        if (typeof _key !== 'string' || _key.length <= 0) {
            throw new Error(`Bad key '${JSON.stringify(_key)}'. Please provide a non-empty string.`);
        }

        this._eventBus.next({ key: _key, data: _data });
        this._eventCacheBus.next({ key: _key, data: _data });
    }

    private keyMatch(eventKey: string, listenerKey: string): boolean {
        const isMatch = (wildcard, key) => (wildcard === star) || (wildcard === key);

        const eventKeyArray = eventKey.split(this.separator);
        const listenerKeyArray = listenerKey.split(this.separator);

        const keyWildcardPairs = eventKeyArray
            .reduce((accum, current, index) => {
                accum.push([current, listenerKeyArray[index]]);
                return accum;
            }, [] as string[][]);

        let isWildcard = false;
        return keyWildcardPairs.every((pair) => {
            const key = pair[0];
            const wildcard = pair[1];
            // '**' match all fragments
            if (wildcard === twoStars && (typeof key !== 'undefined')) {
                isWildcard = true;
                return true;
            }
            // test if fragments match
            if (isMatch(wildcard, key) || isWildcard) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```